# Resizing swap partition (RHEL 5.x)

Tags: linux, partitioning, swap, redhat-enterprise-linux

The following is what parted print outputs:

```
(parted) print                                                            

Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 26.8GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      32.3kB  271MB   271MB   primary  ext2         boot 
 2      271MB   1349MB  1078MB  primary  linux-swap        
 3      1349MB  26.8GB  25.5GB  primary               lvm
```

The volume group created on /dev/sda3 looks like the following:

```
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               rootvg
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  8
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                7
  Open LV               7
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               23.62 GB
  PE Size               128.00 MB
  Total PE              189
  Alloc PE / Size       162 / 20.25 GB
  Free  PE / Size       27 / 3.38 GB
  VG UUID               1Wzcpj-bNMD-cIYr-pOwA-1jdP-f9wE-wiEitV
```

That means there is 3.38GB unused space.

I want to resize my swap partition /dev/sda2 to use 1GB out of the above space. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go ahead and use [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/).

No real reason to muck about on the CLI when you could achieve the same thing faster with a GUI.

---

If you're forced to use a CLI, then you should check out `cfdisk`. It's a little nicer program for partition editing.

Comment: Just figured that installing Gparted is a bit difficult.

Comment: @ring How so? What distro are you running?

Comment: RHEL 5.3 can't pull it through yum

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this online, you could add a new swap partition of 1 GB.  It can be done with `'lvcreate'`, `'fdisk'`, `'mkswap'` and `'swapon'`.

If you do not want 2 swaps fs, you could create a new 2 GB swap, disable the old swap with `'swapoff'` and delete the old lv.

More info [here](http://www.linux.com/news/software/applications/8208-all-about-linux-swap-space).